# Adding a remote git repo through intelliJ

Tags: git, intellij-idea, pycharm

I want to know how to add a remote git repo via intelliJ, not through the git bash. Now, from what I've seen in this [tutorial](http://wiki.jetbrains.net/intellij/Using_Git_Locally#Uploading_the_Master_Branch_to_a_Remote_Repository), it can be done, but whenever I try to push, the dialogue never comes up. If you push to the very bottom, you can see that it can be done in probably a previous version of IntelliJ. How can you do it with version 12 or rather PyCharm 2.6?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

**UPDATE**: this feature is available since 2016.3 version.

`VCS` | `Git` | `Remotes` | `Add` (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Insert</kbd>).

[image: git remotes]

---

Original answer:

You can choose from the existing remotes, but you can't add new remotes from the UI, there is a feature request:

- [IDEA-87099](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-87099) Provide ability to add remote repositories to local git repository

The workaround, for those new to Git is to use the commandline and add a remote like so:

```
git remote add remoteName remoteUrl
```

After that, the remote will show up in the pull dialog in Intellij, but it won't show any branches until you do a fetch, like so:

```
git fetch remoteName
```

Comment: Time passes but the IntelliJ Team it seems does not work on the issue of creating a remote git account from the programme.

Comment: for those of you that are special like me :) make sure (at least in Windows) to change directory to the root of your IntelliJ project where the ".git" folder is then run these commands.

Comment: Good news. This is landing in the next version of Intellij! Check the link above.

Comment: Is there something I'm missing? Cannot find it in IDEA 2021... I see 'VCS' in the menu bar, but from there I cannot find 'Git'

Comment: @alexanderremus VCS | Create Git Repository first.

Answer (score 6):

If you want a menu entry, I think for now the easiest workaround is to create an "external tool" menu entry (Preferences -> Tools -> External Tools -> Add) in IntelliJ or Pycharm. I've created one that calls '/usr/bin/git' with 'remote add origin $Prompt$' (which opens a prompt window asking for the remote git URL) and the current dir field left blank. This works great for my workflow (create local git repository, later push it to a new remote one).

Answer (score 3):

This isn't possible in PyCharm (for now), but if you'd like to use a GUI tool instead of the console, I would recommend [SourceTree](http://www.sourcetreeapp.com/) (free to use).

Once set up in SourceTree (`Repository` -> `Add Remote`), it will be visible and usable in PyCharm as well.

Comment: Not sure how a tool that requires me to log into atlassian is helping to add files to my local git.